# how to add items of listbox to datagridview in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, listbox

i have a listbox with this values :

POW= 0.00 W

CURR= 1.00 A

POW= 0.00 W

CURR= 10.00 A

POW= 5.00 W

CURR= 3.00 A
.
.
.

i want add this itemes to datagridview like this :

2 columns : pow,curr

if iteme is CURR= 3.00 A
add to column of curr
and if item is POW= 4.00 W
add to column of pow

but add only digit of CURR= 3.00 A or pow= 4.00 A 
this means add only 3.00 to curr column and add only 4.00 to pow column

thanks a lot

Comment: please post what you have tried

Answer (score -1):

I'm not going to fix the poor design.

I will post how this program probably should work and leave the implementation to you and then i will post a solution to the way you are doing it.

Better way:
Create class that represents the data (im assuming that power and current can be present in tandem, if not modify this as needed). Create properties to get/set the power and current. and override the ToString as needed (this can be the part that states `$"CURR = {Current} A"` or `"POW = {Power} W"`. Add to a collection (such as a list) the objects to the listbox and bind to ItemsSource the list. Have another list is bound to ItemsSource of the datagridview. When you add items to the list it will auto populate the datagridview. If an item has no current or no power, you can assign that property to be whitespace or "NA".

How you're doing it:

`foreach(var currentitem in listbox.items) {
           if (currentItem.Contains("POW") == true) {add to appropriate column} 
           else if (same thing but for CURR) {add to appropriate column}
}`

for adding to the datagridview you can do datagridview.rows.add or by using the cells method. You haven't provided a lot of info on how to the data needs to be presented